# JavaScript | ReactJS: Parent State-Change Not Triggering Child Props Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, children, setstate

#### Parent setState Triggers `render()`, but Child Component's Props Are Static

This is pretty straight-forward. I have `<Parent />` with a state-property and a handler. Parent passes down both the property and the handler to the child.

The child has a button and invokes its own handler which wraps Parent's handler. A boolean, `isNew`, is passed to Parent -- Parent calls `this.setState({ isNew: isNew })`.

Parent always calls `render` and outputting `isNew` in Parent's HTML shows all is correct. However, `<Child isNew={this.state.isNew} />` never outputs the correct value from `this.props.isNew` -- its always what value is initialized in Parent inside of Parent's `getInitialProps` method.

I just came into this project, but I don't believe we're implementing Flux or Redux within. My assumption was that React, out of the box, **should rerender all children whose props are set to the parent's state**.

In other words, if I have the following:

```
React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<Child isNew={this.state.isNew} handler={this.handler} />);
    }
});
```

When the parent re-renders [from a state-change], all children who rely on the parent's state should also rerender while encapsulating the new state of the parent in its props; assuming a child prop of `<Child property={this.state.property} />`

Am I totally missing something basic here?

Please set me straight on this :)

Thx

Comment: Your assumption is entirely correct, which is demonstrated in this fiddle i made https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42845/ I think you need to post more code to see where the error originates, in particular your method wrapper you mentioned.. but you may as well post the contents of both parent and child components.

Answer (score 0):

I think you set this.props.isNew in child constructor and try print it..

Grand Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class GrandChild extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toogle = this.toogle.bind(this);
  }

  toogle(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.props.toogleParent(!this.props.isNew);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('in grand child', this.props.isNew);
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={this.toogle} href="">click</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GrandChild;
```

Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GrandChild from './grand';


class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('in child', this.props.isNew);
    return (
      <div>
        <GrandChild {...this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './child';

class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isNew: false
    };
    this.toogleParent = this.toogleParent.bind(this);
  }

  toogleParent(isNew) {
    this.setState({ isNew });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('in parent', this.state.isNew);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Main page</h3>
        <Child isNew={this.state.isNew} toogleParent={this.toogleParent} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainPage;
```

Output:

> in parent true
>   in child true
>   in grand child true
>
> in parent false
>   in child false
>   in grand child false
>
> etc..

Comment: Well, this is probably one where I should've posted some code, but the project I'm on is a disaster. In reality, the "`<Child />`" above is actually a `<Grandchild />`, but when I take Grandchild out of Child and make it a direct-descendant of Parent, it all works. Is there any typical reason that Grandchildren don't receive updates from Grandparents?

Comment: I've changed example with grand child, it is works, no barriers don't use grandchild.